# style rule with pseudo element and a pseudoclass in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display the first letter of the first paragraph within the article element with a font size of 2em and vertically aligned with the baseline of the surrounding text. This is my code so far:

```
article p ::first-letter:first-of-type {
  font-size: 2em;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

It didn't have the desired results.
Maybe someone could advise please how i may fix my code to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1):

- Match things in the order that they appear in
- Don't add descendant combinators (spaces) when you aren't trying to match a descendant

Such:

```css
article p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: 2em;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <p>The quick brown fox</p>
  <p>The quick brown fox</p>
  <p>The quick brown fox</p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <p>The quick brown fox</p>
  <p>The quick brown fox</p>
  <p>The quick brown fox</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the pseudo class and the pseudo element, and remove the space character (that serves as descendant combinator):

```
article p:first-of-type::first-letter
```

Comment: You deleted a descendant combinator without comment there